# how to find count of a specific value in column on pandas data frame and use it for calculations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, calculated-columns

I have a pandas data frame similar like mentioned below  and for  all the (Domain) unique value I want to calculate Count(EV)+Count(PV)+count(DV)+count(GV) where values are = green / total count of values in that unique domain

| Domain | EV | PV | DV | GV | Numerator(part) | denominator(part) | ideal Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| KA-BLR | Green | Blue |  | Green | 1 | 6 | 0.166 |
| KA-BLR | Green | Green | Blue |  | 1 | 6 | 0.166 |
| KL-TRV | Green | Blue | Yellow | Red | 0.5 | 7 | 0.071 |
| KL-TRV | Green | Blue | Blue |  | 0.5 | 7 | 0.071 |
| KL-COK | Blue | Blue | Yellow | Green | 0.25 | 4 | 0.0625 |
| TN-CHN | Green |  | Blue |  | 0.5 | 5 | 0.1 |
| TN-CHN | Green | Blue |  | Yellow | 0.5 | 5 | 0.1 |

Sample Code

```
OVER_ALL_SCORE = {}
for Domain in df_RR["Domain"].unique():

   #count of greens 

    EV_G = (df_RR['EV'] == 'Green').sum()
    
    PV_G = (df_RR['PV'] == 'Green').sum()
    
    DV_G = (df_RR['DV'] == 'Green').sum()
    
    GV_G= (df_RR['GV'] == 'Green').sum()

    #count of all values excluding null

    EV = df_RR['EV'].sum()
    
    PV = df_RR['PV'].sum()
    
    DV = df_RR['DV'].sum()
    
    GV = df_RR['GV'] .sum()
    
    
       
    # so (0.25*(SUM for "DV" of greens (totally correct))+0.25*(SUM for "PV" of greens (totally correct))+0.25*(SUM for "EV" of greens (totally correct))+0.25*(SUM for "GV" of greens (totally correct)) / total count of values
    
   Numerator = (0.25*EV_G) + (0.25*PV_G) + (0.25* DV_G) + (0.25* GV_G)
   

   denominator = EV+PV+DV+GV

   try:
      OVER_ALL_SCORE [domain]=(Numerator /denominator )
   
  except:
        OVER_ALL_SCORE [domain]=0

 df_RR['Overall_score']=df_RR['Domain'].map(OVER_ALL_SCORE)
```

Currently this logic is returning same value across all the domain. please help in resolving it

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you post your ideal output?

Comment: @Umar.H i have updated the question with ideal output ( including the numerator and  denominator) part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that gives the ideal output:

```
OVER_ALL_SCORE = {}

for Domain in df_RR["Domain"].unique():

    sub_df = df_RR.loc[df_RR['Domain']==Domain]

    #count of greens 

    EV_G = (sub_df['EV'] == 'Green').sum()
    PV_G = (sub_df['PV'] == 'Green').sum()
    DV_G = (sub_df['DV'] == 'Green').sum()
    GV_G = (sub_df['GV'] == 'Green').sum()

    #count of all values

    EV = sub_df['EV'].count()
    PV = sub_df['PV'].count()
    DV = sub_df['DV'].count()
    GV = sub_df['GV'].count()

    numerator = (0.25*EV_G) + (0.25*PV_G) + (0.25* DV_G) + (0.25* GV_G)
    denominator = EV+PV+DV+GV

    try:
        OVER_ALL_SCORE[Domain] = (numerator /denominator )
    except:
        OVER_ALL_SCORE[Domain] = 0

df_RR['Overall_score']=df_RR['Domain'].map(OVER_ALL_SCORE)
```

There are a few changes are were key:

**count() vs. sum()**

In your count of ALL VALUES you'll want to use the `count` method rather than the `sum` method (otherwise, this code will just concatenate the string values in the table):

```
df_RR['EV'].sum()
```

This returns: 'GreenGreenGreenBlueGreen' (since the sum method simply adds all of the values in the series).

Use this instead:

```
df_RR['EV'].count()
```

The reason it works in your count of the greens is that  this code `df_RR['EV'] == 'Green'` is returning a series of booleans which can be summed correctly to give you the number of greens (since it will add the trues as 1's and the falses as zeros):

`True True True False True` is the same as `1 1 1 0 1`

**The Main Problem**

Currently, your counts are the same in each loop that you run since you're not filtering according to the domain. I would create sub-dataframe. Based on the domain you're looking at as the first step in your loop:

```
domain_df = df_RR.loc[df_RR['Domain'] == Domain]
```

Comment: thanks for the solution , i have updated the question with expected output . hope that defines the problem more clearly

Comment: Thanks for the ideal output. That was helpful. I think I've solved the problem.